# How to scp log files for a specific date from a server

Tags: linux

I am trying to scp log files (for a specific date only) from a server. The log files are in location /var/log/service.

eg: `ssh centos@Server "ls -lh /var/log/service | grep 'Oct 22'"`

Its showing me the file name.
But I want to scp that file

Answer (score 1):

**Short story:**

```
$ ssh centos@Server '(cd /var/log/service && find .  -newermt 2020-10-22 -a ! -newermt 2020-10-23 | tar -T - -jcf -)' | tar -C /target/directory -j -x -f -
```

**Long story:**

Read on.

## SSH Remote Command Invocation

You use ssh to invoke a remote command,

```
$ ssh centos@Server "ls -lh /var/log/service | grep 'Oct 22'"
```

On the remote side, `centos@Server`, the ssh daemon attached to your
ssh/login connection executes a pipeline,

```
$ ls -lh /var/log/service | grep 'Oct 22'
```

The remote ssh takes the standard output of it, still on
`centos@Server`, transfers it over the ssh connection, and outputs it
*locally*, on the local standard output (your terminal).

You could have just as well said,

```
$ ssh centos@Server "ls -lh /var/log/service" | grep 'Oct 22'
```

Note the subtle difference: instead of executing the entire pipe
remotely (your original remote command embeds the pipe char `|` inside
the quotes), now you have `|` unquoted, and two commands connected by it,

1. `ssh centos@Server "ls -lh /var/log/service"`. This executes `ls`
   remotely and brings its standard output over the ssh connection.
2. `grep 'Oct 22'` runs locally, and filters the output of the ssh command just as before. Only locally.

## `find` and `tar`

Login interactively to `centos@Server`, and execute the following commands:

```
$ cd /var/log/service
$ find .  -newermt 2020-10-22 -a ! -newermt 2020-10-23
```

You will see a list of the files (and directories, and other entries
that may exist) you want to copy over. `man find` will tell you what
the `-newermt` option does, and how to tune the selection criteria.

It is this list of entries that can be used as *input list* with tar,

```
$ cd /var/log/service
$ find .  -newermt 2020-10-22 -a ! -newermt 2020-10-23 > /tmp/filelist
$ tar -T /tmp/filelist -c -j -f /tmp/archive.tar.bz2
```

Better yet, not using a temporary file that will be left over,

```
$ cd /var/log/service
$ find .  -newermt 2020-10-22 -a ! -newermt 2020-10-23 | tar -T - -c -j -f /tmp/archive.tar.bz2
```

Or, even better, using a subshell to not change the current working
directory at all for the invoking shell (thereby increasing job
security),

```
$ (cd /var/log/service && find .  -newermt 2020-10-22 -a ! -newermt 2020-10-23 | tar -T - -c -j -f /tmp/archive.tar.bz2)
```

This single command now creates a file `/tmp/archive.tar.bz2` on the
remote system.

As a variation, for demostration: another command can be used (still
logged in interactively) to count the number of bytes that the archive
would have - without actually creating the archive:

```
$ (cd /var/log/service && find .  -newermt 2020-10-22 -a ! -newermt 2020-10-23 | tar -T - -c -j -f -) | wc -c
```

Instead of using `-f ...` to create a file, you use `-f -` to write to
standard output instead; `wc -c` then counts the characters from
standard input.

## Bringing it all Together

That said, the command

```
$ ssh centos@Server '(cd /var/log/service && find .  -newermt 2020-10-22 -a ! -newermt 2020-10-23 | tar -T - -jcf -)' | tar -C /target/directory -j -x -f -
```

invokes our weird pipeline remotely, with the purpose of writing a
`bzip2` compressed `tar` archive into the ssh connection as standard
output. On the local side, we use `tar` to unpack that stream/archive
from standard input. (Before unpacking, you tell `tar` to move itself
into `/target/directory` to not empty a can of dirt into your living
room.)

Comment: This worked!! very detailed explanation!,   Also use of **sed** worked eg: `ssh -i sshKey user@host "sed -n '/startDate startTime:*/,/endDate endTime:*/p' /var/log/LogLocation  >> filename.log` . I can use this as the logfile has text like "2020-07-01 00:08:54" so it gets all content between the given timings